# How to setup Visual Studio 2015 colours for variable name smart tag

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Imagine you have variable x. then you change its name to x1 and you got something like a smart tag, so you can rename all the uses of the variable in one go (eg using Alt Shift F10)..

In previous versions it was nice little red dash under the last letter of the name

In 2015 Microsoft newly appointed geniuses decided to take on Resharper. They added this crazy bulb (it irritates me more than that friendly paperclip they added as MS Office Assistant 15 yrs ago)..

But ignoring the bulb - now the variable name is embraced in some stupid dashed border which makes impossible to read it efficiently..

[rant] It basically works as camo used in military - eroding an object shape to reduce positive recognition by enemy (which is consistent with the latests Microsoft policies. Balmer was a clown but he put developers in the center stage. This new guy hates developers). [/rant]

I scrolled through all the Font and Colors menu but couldnt find it

**Is there a way to remove this border?**

[image]

Comment: I don't have VS 2015, so this is just a wild guess, but you probably can't change the border. You probably *can* change the background color (I'm betting it's one of the refactoring colors) to make it easier to read the text. Or set the background color to the same as the default background color to make it effectively disappear.

Comment: problem is in the border.. to achieve it through bg colours i will need then change all the text bg to dark gray and fore to white then border will disapper.. but that is even worse for me (some people like inverted colours i dont)